# Kafka connect doesn't find available brokers when volume attached

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, bitnami

**Symptom** : A modified bitnami kafka image contains the kafka-connect jars, they work fine.
But once I add a volume for persistence, it can't find existing brokers.

**Details**:
I modded the bitnami image in a way to copy the connect jars and launching the connect-distributed.sh.
It works fine, connectors can consume and produce from/to the topics

But once I add persistent volume to the kafka image, the first startup is ok but the next onwards dont.  connect.log says:

```
"[2020-05-21 15:59:34,786] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=my-group1] Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:297)
g.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error fetching metadata for topic connect-offsets
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.getTopicMetadata(Fetcher.java:403)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(KafkaConsumer.java:1965)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(KafkaConsumer.java:1933)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.start(KafkaBasedLog.java:138)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.start(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:109)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.start(Worker.java:186)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.startServices(AbstractHerder.java:123)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:284)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor is below 1 or larger than the number of available brokers."
```

The kafka itself still works well, every topic is present (replfactor of 1) and I can consumer/produce messages by hand. And I can also launch the connector system by hand successfully.

**edit:** My guess is that without PV it will start the connectors after kafka is up, but with PV it sees immediatly that connectors are already present and tries to load them before the kafka started.

**edit2:**
   modded image:

```
    FROM bitnami/kafka
    // copying connect jars..
    ADD connect-distributed.properties /opt/prop/connect-distributed.properties
    ADD modded-kafka-run.sh /opt/bitnami/scripts/kafka/run.sh
    RUN chmod 755 /opt/bitnami/scripts/kafka/run.sh
```

modded run.sh(I just added the distributed.sh and curl to it):

```
    info "** Starting Kafka **"
    /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/connect-distributed.sh -daemon /opt/prop/connect-distributed.properties
   //.. adding the connectors with curl
    if am_i_root; then
        exec gosu "$KAFKA_DAEMON_USER" "${START_COMMAND[@]}"
    else
        exec "${START_COMMAND[@]}"
    fi
```

original run.sh: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-kafka/blob/master/2/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/scripts/kafka/run.sh

Comment: Can you share details of the image? It's hard to help without knowing that. You might also want to check out https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base

Comment: @RobinMoffatt  I edited my question.   I am aware the separated docker exists for the connectors, but would like to solve this inside the kafka image itself.

Comment: So you're trying to run Kafka Broker and Kafka Connect worker in the same container?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to configure it on a way I would in a noncontainerized way on my local machine

Comment: If that's your aim then it sounds like you'd be better off with a straightforward VM to be honest :-)

Comment: Please use Docker Compose that Bitnami already provides, never run more than one service in a container

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what the issue is, but the `ENTRYPOINT` that starts Kafka actually starts **after** any `RUN` command.

Not clear why you need to create your own Kafka Connect image when [at least](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker) [two](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-images) exist

You should be using docker-compose to start 3 separate Zookeeper, Kafka, and Connect clusters